# Replacing smart quote with regular quote causes entire string to be erased

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have some files that were originally RTF files. They were opened with Microsoft Word 2016 and saved as .txt files. No other changes were made to the files. They were transferred to a Linux system.

When using the command:

`file myfile.txt` on the Linux they are showing as `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`.

I am reading the files into PHP and processing them line by line. I am trying to replace any right smart-quotes with regular single quotes, but my entire string is being erased.

My code looks like this:

```
$text = "I can’t go for supper";
$text = preg_replace('/\x{2019}/u', "'", $text);
echo $text;
```

The apostrophe here is a right smart quote which shows up in Vim as `<92>`. Upon researching on the web, I have discovered this is actually unicode character `2019`.

However, when I try to display the new value of `$text` nothing is displayed.

What is wrong with my code and why is it wiping out the entire string of text?

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://3v4l.org/8aBbH

Comment: Dunno https://3v4l.org/f5Gu7

Comment: The problem is that those quotes on 3v4l.org are not being displayed as code <92> so is not a true representation.

Comment: What do you mean by code `<92>`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver In typing a response to you, I discovered that character code <92> is specifically part of the Windows-1252 encoding set. I believe that the solution is to use iconv() on each line that I read in.

Answer (score 4):

Upon further research, I have determined that character code `<92>` is specific to the Windows-1252 character encoding. I first needed to convert it to UTF-8 before I was able to manipulate the string.

The following code works correctly:

```
$text = "I can’t go for supper";
$text = iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\x{2019}/u', "'", $text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Good job researching this.